# In what Vedic Literature can the following cosmological model

Tags: puranas, bhagavata-purana, cosmology

I watched the following [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WZ6EmFV08A&t=530s) to see whether it sheds some light on the cosmological model found in the *Bhagavatam*; however, I found that the video gave a different cosmological model and called it a part of Vedic cosmology that can be found in the Vedic literature. Here is the model:

> > Chandra Mandal, whose lok is Chandra lok (moon) revolves around the Bhu Mandal, whose lok is Bhu lok. Bhu Mandal revolves around the Surya Mandal whose lok is the sun; it is also called svarg in the video. The space in between Bhu Mandal and Surya Mandal is called Bhuva. Bhu + Bhuva + Svarg creates the first triloki.

> > The Surya Mandal revolves around the Paramesthi Mandal, whose lok is Jana lok. The space in between is called Maha, and Svarg + Maha + Jana creates the second triloki.

> > The Paramesthi Mandal revolves around the Svyambhu Mandal whose lok is Satya loka, the abode of Lord Brahma. The space in between is called Tapa, and Jana + Tapa + Satya created the third triloki

Some of the names match those found in the *Bhagavatam*, but I do not find any mentions about the mandalas rotating about other mandalas. What Vedic literature mentions the model stated in the video?

Comment: the gayatri mantra

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow Thank you very much, but it seems to me that the gaytri mantra only mentions the first triloki. Please let me know if the mantra secretly mentions other trilokis and mandals

Comment: no, it mentions all of them. see sapvyahriti

Comment: @YOuwillnotknow I googles "Sapvyahriti" but found a bunch of different things. Do you have a pdf document of the text you mentioned? If so, can you upload those texts (or entire document) that mention everything I said in my post?

Comment: @Debbie if it's not in writing in text it isn't a real verse.

Answer (score 0):

@Debbie The loks are uttered as part of sandhya vandana. Here is the text:

Om bhuh, Om BhuvaH, Om SuvaH, Om MahaH, Om JanaH, Om TapaH, Om Satyam.
Om tat savitur varenyaM, bhargo, devasya dhImahi, dhIyo yo naH, prachodayAt

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).